# how works referencing in js?

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

How know js??  :D

```
    let obj = {}
    let anotherObj = obj
```

Now `anotherObj` contain `{}` value as reference on `obj`. 
So `anotherObj` has only reference on `obj`. But when we reassign new value to `obj`
Why assigning in js works in this way? 
And I know this feature provide usefull monkeypatching technic

```
    anotherObj // {}
    obj = null
    anotherObj // {}
```

Variable `anotherObj` still contain `{}` value. 
**But** `anotherObj` is a reference on `obj` and as I understand it should contain `null` as `obj`

Comment: Take a look at the answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding the way that "references" work. You're thinking in terms of `pointers` like in C. When you see...

```
var obj = {};
var anotherObj = obj;
```

...you're thinking `obj` references an object and `anotherObj` references `obj` which references an object. You're thinking in terms of a chain of references. But that's not how assignment works in most languages unless you're using `pointers` or other address space references.

Instead, what happens is `var obj = {};` creates an object in some memory location, and `obj` now contains that memory location. When you do `var anotherObj = obj;`, then `obj` gets evaluated as that memory location and that memory location now gets assigned as the value to `anotherObj`. So now rather than `anotherObj` pointing to `obj`, we have both `obj` and `anotherObj` pointing to the same memory location of the obj.

So, when we do `obj = null`, we're only changing the value that `obj` points to--`anotherObj` is still pointing to the memory location of the object we created.

To my knowledge, there's no way to update all of your object references or even to delete the object manually (e.g. replacing it with `null` like you're trying to do). If your intent is to do something like that for the purpose of managing object life cycle, then you're going to be disappointed. Instead, you're going to need to take an alternative approach like storing the object in a global variable and then using that global reference as opposed to several local references.

Comment: Thanks, I got it